# NSString to NSDate keeps getting null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I know this been asked for so many times but I always end up getting null in my NSDate. I have a string like this "January 16, 2012 21:44:56" I want to convert it to "January 16, 2012 09:44:56 PM". I want to add a PM in the converted date and convert the 24 hour time format to 12 hour time format. Here's my code.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY HH:ii:ss a"];

    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: You do not need to alloc/init the `NSDate` since this will leak when you assing a new `NSDate` to it which is returned from the methods `dateFromString:`. Just do `NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ali3n correctly pointed out, you should first set the format of `dateString` to the formatter to get a valid date object. Next you should set the formatter's format to the desired one and continue. Do the following:

```
NSString *dateString = @"January 16, 2012 21:44:56";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateFromString;
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString *stringFromDate  = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Answer (score 2):

`@"MMMM dd, YYYY HH:ii:ss a"` this format should match with the date the ypu are passing to the date formatter ..

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your format string an also you need to tell the formatter the Locale in which your date string is presented.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release], dateFormatter = nil;
```

Setting the Local is very important since you have an name of a date in your input. You will need to tell the  `NSDateFormatter` is wich language the name will be. In the example given it is in english. I've you run you code without setting the local on a device where the language is not set to english it wil fail to parse the date.

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape literals in the format string.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd',' YYYY HH:ii:ss a"];
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your requirements you have to change the dateFormatter.Check this [link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/simple-methods-for-date-formatting-and.html) for more.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```